# rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0 does nothing

Tags: windows-10, command-line, sleep, hibernate

Originally, my question began a little differently:

When I am using BigBox (Launchbox), I choose the "Sleep" option, and it kept putting my laptop to hibernate.  I could not wake the machine via keyboard or mouse, only power button.  If I disable hibernate, the "Sleep" option in BigBox does not work at all.  I click the "Sleep" option, and BigBox just makes a noise.

However, I CAN sleep by just using the Windows menu at the bottom-left.  BigBox DOES sleep when I install it on my other laptop, and on my Windows 10 PC, so it seems to be isolated to my Gateway Laptop (Model: GWTN156-7BK).

I did a lot of messing around, and now, I'm not sure if the issue is isolated to BigBox.  It might be more of a general Windows issue.

With hibernate turned ON, the following command puts my machine to hibernate (which is expected behavior, as I understand it)

```
    rundll32.exe powrprof.dll, SetSuspendState Sleep
```

So, I disabled hibernate, and now, when I run the sleep command, nothing at all happens.  (When I hit enter, it just goes to the next line of the command line.  No error message)

I also tried:
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0

Event viewer shows:

```
User-mode process attempted to change the system state by calling SetSuspendState or SetSystemPowerState APIs.
```

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" /> 
  <EventID>187</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>243</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000400000000404</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-11-28T20:28:04.3791459Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>21998</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="984" ThreadID="8572" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-HOHLCJ3</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-4090141023-304028169-1425888792-1002" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="ApiCallerNameLength">53</Data> 
  <Data Name="ApiCallerName">\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe</Data> 
  <Data Name="SystemAction">3</Data> 
  <Data Name="LightestSystemState">2</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Also, I understand that there are better ways to sleep a PC rather than using this command line.  However, I'd like to understand what's going on, because I'm GUESSING that it's a clue to my original problem (BigBox SLEEP command hibernates when hibernate is enabled, BUT, it does nothing when hibernate is disabled.  In other words, BigBox is behaving just like the command line, so I'm GUESSING it's doing something similar.)  I'm hoping that if I can figure out why the command line doesn't work, it gives me a clue as to why BigBox behaves the same way.

Answer (score 1):

using the tool @DrMoishe Pippik mentioned, i found out using it to turn off the monitor actually puts my computer to sleep.

`psshutdown64.exe -x`

The time parameter seems to be in hours and not seconds, but i didnt bother testing.
So im just gonna use task scheduler instead or some other app to run the command as a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Sysinternals (now part of Microsoft) has the tool [psshutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown), specifically because not all shutdown option are readily available from the CMD or batch files. Use the following to Sleep, perhaps adding the full path to the file location:

`psshutdown64.exe -d -t 0`

Of course, waking up from sleep depends on your settings. [This PC is set to ignore mouse movement (lest jostling the table wake the PC), but hitting a key wakes it.]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for an alternative way to shut down using the command line.  Instead, I'm trying to understand why the command line I am using behaves this way.  The reason why I'm asking is because I'm trying to troubleshoot why BigBox behaves this same way.  I do not know how their software sends the Sleep command, but I'm guessing it's done the same way I am doing it.  Since BigBox is behaving the same way as that command line, I'm trying to understand that command line to see if it gives a clue as to why BigBox can't sleep.

Comment: I just tried psshutdown, but it says C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop\SystemSleep\PSTools>psshutdown64.exe -d -t 0

PsShutdown v2.53 - Shutdown, logoff and power manage local and remote systems
Copyright (C) 1999-2021 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Error shutting down system: The request is not supported.